# How to disable EDIT tab for webform?

Tags: 7

It would be great if anyone tell me how to disable EDIT Tab. I'm using Drupal 7.

I try with role permission, I successfully disable it for other submitter but failed to do the same for some submitter.

At the same time, I want that the submitter be able to change the workflow state, this is why i check all that permissions.

Thanks for the help.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Go to people >> permissions

Comment: What role is this? Everything is checked off.

Comment: A manager role with permissions to change workflow state of webform submissions without having access to edit the submission, i'm working with webform module

Comment: You may need to clear the cache after you changed the role permission,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had installed module [tabtamer](https://www.drupal.org/project/tabtamer) and it worked exactly like i want.

> Tab Tamer is an administration utility that provides easy re-ordering, hiding, and deactivation of tabs and subtabs. You can also rename tab labels.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the roles in question, remove their ability to edit webform content types and make sure they don't have something like administer nodes checked off. It sounds like they may have too many permissions assigned to the role(s) that would cause the edit tab to appear. Also uncheck permissions pertaining to 'submissions' other than administrative roles.

Comment: I uncheck all role permissions pertaining to 'submissions' but nothing change, can the problem  be overcome from view access permissions ?